# Why we have separate Interface called Entry which is nested in Map Interface in JAVA

Tags: java, oop

We know Map is an Interface which is being implemented by classes HashMap, TreeMap...

Since all these implementing classes have same entry pattern (i.e. key-value pair),
why should not we have this Entry pattern within Map Interface itself?

What is the purpose to have this Entry pattern separately as Interface that is nested inside Map Interface?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A `Map` is in a sense a collection of `Entry` objects. How would you expect it to be an entry? Can you give an example of how `Map` would be defined as an interface/contract to implement `Entry`?

Comment: They could have done that, but since `Entry` belongs to `Map`, i believe they wanted to put it inside the `Map` interface.

Comment: I agree. As you said, Map is a collection of Entry objects but my questions is why we need to have this entry as separate interface by design, since all the map implementing classes have same pattern of objects as entry. Why don't we have all the methods declared in 'Entry' interface is not declared in 'Map' itself? @ Ernest Kiwele

Comment: @Anonymous The methods of a single `Entry` are related to that single entry. The methods of a `Map` are related to all the entries. `Entry` has a method `getKey()`, if it was in `Map`, which key would it return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `Map.Entry` is encapsulated within `Map` is because it is a very intimate strongly coupled interface that is purposely designed to be used with a `Map` exclusively. For your intents and purposes you can see it as a pair (key and value) representing one single entry in the `Map`.

Different Map implementations have different requirements about how to store the entries. A `HashMap` computes the hash code of the key and stores it in its `Node` implementation (which extends `Map.Entry`), while `TreeMap`'s `Entry` has information like the parent entry, the left and right children and the 'colour' of the node (since it is a red-black tree). Each `Map` implementation has its own requirements, so the `Entry` was kept as an interface.

Answer (score 0):

The `Map` interface has one purpose - represent a mapping of keys to values. The `Map.Entry` interface has a different purpose - represent a single key-value pair.

> why should not we have this Entry pattern within Map Interface itself?

If you mean to ask why not declare the methods of the `Map.Entry` interface directly in the `Map` interface, that wouldn't make much sense, since a `Map` contains multiple keys and values, so which key and value would the `getKey()` and `getValue()` methods return if they were part of the `Map` interface?

Besides, the `Map.Entry` interface is useful when you want to iterate over the entries of a `Map`. You call the `entrySet()` method and get a `Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>`.

Comment: IMO he meant why the `Map.Entry` interface is nested inside the `Map` interface, not within its own file, so this should not be the answer.